# how to make sure the color fill in the entire bottom navigation view?

Tags: android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I'm facing a problem right now that i tried to imply the color function background in the `app:itemBackground="@color/purpleBoo"`

but the color seems like not to fill in the entire bottom navigation? why is this happening to me?

[image]

my bottom navigation code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/purpleBoo"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show the parent... you have a margin applied somewhere.

Comment: i didn't apply any margin

Comment: Did you try the LayoutInspector to inspect your layout at this time? You'll be able to see what that white space is (or where it comes from). There's clearly something adding space there, so if you don't know where it's coming from, neither can we; however, once you have the app running, head over Tools -> LayoutInspector, attach to your process and observe all the Window elements until you find where this comes from.

Comment: i can't find the solution?

Comment: If you can't find it with the project in front of you, how can we do it w/out it. The only think we know is your XML. I just copied and pasted it into a blank xml. I replaced the colors for `@android:color/holo_green_light` but the bar spans the width of the device as expected. So you have a Margin applied either to the root of this fragment (at activity level) or the Fragment container in the activity has a padding/margin, or your style is applying margin/padding. The BottomNavigationView has nothing to do with this, and neither does the fragment as pictured. That's as much as I can help you.

Comment: Post a picture of the LayoutInspector where the layout is visible...

Answer (score 0):

For the current layout that you are using the bottom navigation panel can be maximized to width "match_parent" so the color will also be available inside the width section.

Well, in case the white space around the panel is disturbing the look of your app then you can change the background of the layout as a whole then that would seem better.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the android  **android:background="@color/purpleBoo"** in  BottomNavigationView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/purpleBoo"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            android:background="@color/purpleBoo"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```